# How do I store a Swift struct in Core Data on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, struct

At the moment I'm storing one of my classes as NSData in a plist and obviously that isn't a good way to do it.

So I'm trying to set up Core Data, but my class has Structs. This is what I have:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Favourite: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var origin: Stop

    struct Stop {
        var name: String;
        var id: String;
    }
}
```

But this is no good because it says:

> Property cannot be marked as @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Furthermore, if this error did not occur, I don't know what I'd set it up as in my xcdatamodeld file.

I guess I could store the values in the struct and assign on initialisation of the object? Is this the most optimal/clean way?

Comment: Consider to redesign your model to turn the struct into a Core Data entity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I will proceed like this :

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

    struct Stop {
       var name: String;
       var id: String;
    }

    class Favourite: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var name: String
        @NSManaged var id: String

        var stop : Stop {
           get {
                return Stop(name: self.name, id: self.id)
            }
            set {
                self.name = newValue.name
                self.id = newValue.id
            }
         }
    }
```

Very interesting article, you should read: http://www.jessesquires.com/better-coredata-models-in-swift/

Comment: This is what I was hoping to avoid having to do as I have a few of these Structs, but that looks to be what I will have to end up doing. Thanks

Comment: The other option is to make `Stop` conform to `NSCoding`, but that would amount to more or less the same thing even if it could be done on a plain Swift struct.

Comment: @TomHarrington could you make an example 