# iOS - Save array of struct in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, struct

I have a struct like this:

```
     struct list
{
        
         var userId: Int = 0
         var id: Int = 0
         var title: String = ""
         var body: String = ""

}
```

In another part of my program, I declare an array of struct and I enter information through a JSON files downloaded from the internet.

```
var array = [list]()
```

Now my problem is to save and recuperar this array of struct in CoreData. I do not know how to go forward, would you give me a hand?

Comment: what is your CoreData Model?. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876275/how-do-i-store-a-swift-struct-in-core-data-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you best choice is to go with Binary Data type.

1.Create a `toDictionary()` method on your struct model:

```
func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    return ["userId: self.userId, "id": self.id, ...]
}
```

2.Then add a NSData property on your core data model, which represents your struct list:

`@NSManaged var list: NSData?`

3.Access that list property with a class helper:

```
func listDictionary() -> [String: Any]? {
    guard let listData = self.list as? Data else { return nil }
    let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: listData) as? [String: Any]
    return dict
}
```

4.Create a `fromDictionary() -> list` on your list object which will build a model from dictionary