# How to save struct in coredata

Tags: ios, swift3

please help me. I have coredata model with one attribute called scores as Transformable type. I have struct called Scores like this.

```
struct PlayerScoresDict : Codable
{
    var round : Int?
    var score : String?
    var cards : Array<Int>?

}
struct PlayersDict : Codable
{
    var id : Int?
    var scoreDict  : PlayerScoresDict?

}
```

and i am saving PlayersDict in array. and i want to save this array in coredata scores object. But i am getting error. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

change struct to class.
It working with me!

```
class PlayerScoresDict : Codable {
    var round : Int?
    var score : String?
    var cards : Array<Int>?
}


class PlayersDict : Codable {
    var id : Int?
    var scoreDict  : PlayerScoresDict?
}
```

[in coredate set like that if you want an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Xck.png)

Comment: Hi Long Vu, Thanks for reply. But still i cannot add to coredata getting error while saving. Can you share your code, how you did and added to coredata.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876275/how-do-i-store-a-swift-struct-in-core-data-on-ios