# How to save custom struct in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift

Need to save my big custom struct in Core Data, but `ValueTransformer` can't archive data and I get error:

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4866 "The data couldn’t be written because it isn’t in the correct format." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600002d70ba0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class '__SwiftValue' does not adopt it." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class '__SwiftValue' does not adopt it.}}}"

Below my `ValueTransformer` class and model which I want to save

```
class MyValueTransformer: ValueTransformer {

override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    
    guard let model = value as? CoreDataModel else { print("HUI"); return nil }
    
    do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: model, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        print("value transformer do")
        return data
    } catch {
        print(error) // Catch this error which i describe higher
        print("value transformer catch")
        return nil
    }
}
```

MODEL:

[image]

Model's rows:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876275/how-do-i-store-a-swift-struct-in-core-data-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

What the error tells you is that `NSSecureCoding`, which is used by `NSKeyedArchiver` **does not support Swift `struct`**. It can only work with classes that inherit from `NSObject` (note the `NS*` preefix - any time you see it, you are on Objective-C land), i.e.:

```
class X: NSObject { }
```

Conforming to `Codable` is not going to help.

So you have 2 options:

1. Convert your `struct`s to `class`es and get them to inherit from `NSObject`, as well as `NSCoding` or `NSSecureCoding`. This is the simpler option.
2. Leave original structures intact, but create their corresponding helper classes that do implement `NSObject` and `NSCoding` or `NSSecureCoding`. This solution is described [here](https://swiftandpainless.com/nscoding-and-swift-structs/)

Note that you will also have trouble with `enum PurpleType: String` with NSCoding, as (as enums can only be `Int` in Objective-C land)

Comment: Can u help me with enum? how I can to do string enum with NSCoding?